# How to find a vector space that only violates VS1, and another one only violates VS2?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find two vector spaces over F, with operations +,·
one only violates VS1, and the other one only violates VS2.

I tried to define x+y = log(x) + log(y)
and x·y is as usual.
,which violates VS2 and VS7... that's the best I can do.

Need some help!
Thanks.

Comment: Please say exactly what your vector space axioms (1 and 2) are. You can't assume we all know them in the identical order.

Comment: If they violate one of the axioms, you should not call them vector spaces. Apart from that, not everybody uses the same axioms or the same numbering, so you should be more specific for the question to be comprehensible.

Comment: Sorry............The VS1 is for any x, y in V x+y=y+x. The VS2 is (x+y)+z=x+(y+z).